# Derivation of the variation of parameters in Second-Order Differential Eq.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In Second-Order ODEs ,There is a problem which I haven't solved.

Method of Variation of Parameters;

In derivation of the method , there is a part which is following.
$$k'[2Pu'_1 + Qu_1] + k''[Pu_1]=0 \\
k'=\frac{e^{-\int [Q/P]dx}}{u_1^2}$$
But I find  $$k=\frac{e^{-\int [Q/P]dx}}{u_1^2}$$
I could't understand how they find k' like that.İs it typo or my result is wrong ?

Here is my attempt to solve;

$$[2Pu'_1 + Qu_1]\frac{dk}{dx}=-[Pu_1]\frac{d(\frac{dk}{dx})}{dx} \\
\int [2Pu'_1 + Qu_1]dk=\int [Pu_1]d(\frac{dk}{dx}) \\
[2Pu'_1 + Qu_1]k=[Pu_1]\frac{dk}{dx} \\
k=\frac{e^{-\int [Q/P]dx}}{u_1^2}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result with $k'$ is correct. The ODE is a first order ODE for $\kappa(x) = k'(x)$, given by
\begin{equation}
 \kappa' P u_1 + \kappa(2 P u_1' + Q u_1) = 0,
\end{equation}
which can be solved for $\kappa$, yielding
\begin{equation}
 \kappa(x) = c_1 \frac{e^{-\frac{Q}{x P}}}{u_1(x)^2}.
\end{equation}

**Addition based on edited question:** Let's solve your equation step by step. I'm making the $x$-dependence of all the functions involved explicit, because this matters quite a lot.

The equation you would like to solve is
\begin{equation}
P(x) u_1(x) \frac{\text{d}^2 k}{\text{d} x^2}(x) + \frac{\text{d} k}{\text{d} x}(x) \left( 2 P(x) \frac{\text{d} u_1}{\text{d} x} + Q(x)\, u_1(x)\right) = 0. \tag{1}
\end{equation}
Assuming that $P(x) \neq 0$, $u_1(x) \neq 0$ and $\frac{\text{d} k}{\text{d} x} \neq 0$ on the domain in question, we can rewrite $(1)$ to get
\begin{align}
\frac{\frac{\text{d}^2 k}{\text{d} x^2}(x)}{\frac{\text{d} k}{\text{d} x}(x)} &= -\frac{ 2 P(x) \frac{\text{d} u_1}{\text{d} x} + Q(x)\, u_1(x)}{P(x) u_1(x)}\\
&= -2\frac{\frac{\text{d} u_1}{\text{d} x}}{u_1(x)} -\frac{Q(x)}{P(x)}. \tag{2}
\end{align}
To solve this equation, we can integrate on both sides to $x$. Forget things like 'multiplying by $\text{d}x$', because this suggests that $\text{d}x$ is a quantity with which you can calculate without problems, which isn't true. Moreover, having a quite complicated ODE such as $(2)$, with a number of $x$-dependent functions involved, it is easy to loose track of what the dependent variable is.

Let's first integrate the left hand side of $(2)$. To do that, we can recognise the integrand as the derivative of $\ln \frac{\text{d} k}{\text{d} x}(x)$, so that
\begin{equation}
 \int^x \frac{\frac{\text{d}^2 k}{\text{d} x^2}(x)}{\frac{\text{d} k}{\text{d} x}(x)}\,\text{d} x = \int^x \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} x}\left[\ln \frac{\text{d} k}{\text{d} x}(x)\right]\,\text{d} x = \ln \frac{\text{d} k}{\text{d} x}(x) + c_1,\tag{3}
\end{equation}
because the integral of a derivative is just the function itself. Here, $c_1$ is just an integration constant.

The integral to $x$ of the right hand side of $(2)$ can be split into two parts, namely
\begin{equation}
 \int^x -2\frac{\frac{\text{d} u_1}{\text{d} x}}{u_1(x)} -\frac{Q(x)}{P(x)}\,\text{d} x = -2 \int^x \frac{\frac{\text{d} u_1}{\text{d} x}}{u_1(x)} \,\text{d} x - \int^x \frac{Q(x)}{P(x)}\,\text{d} x. \tag{4}
\end{equation}
Similar to $(3)$, we can recognise the integrand of the first integral in $(4)$ as the derivative of $\ln u_1(x)$, so that
\begin{equation}
  -2 \int^x \frac{\frac{\text{d} u_1}{\text{d} x}}{u_1(x)} \,\text{d} x =  -2 \int^x \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} x}\left[\ln u_1(x)\right] \,\text{d} x = -2 \ln u_1(x) + c_2. \tag{5}
\end{equation}
Because $P$ and $Q$ are general, we can't really say anything useful about the integral $\int^x \frac{Q(x)}{P(x)}\,\text{d} x$, so we leave that as it is.

Combining the results of $(3)$,$(4)$ and $(5)$ in $(2)$, we get
\begin{equation}
 \ln \frac{\text{d} k}{\text{d} x}(x) = -2 \ln u_1(x) - \int^x \frac{Q(x)}{P(x)}\,\text{d} x + c, \tag{6}
\end{equation}
where both integration constants $c_{1,2}$ are combined in $c$. We can solve $(6)$ for $\frac{\text{d} k}{\text{d} x}(x)$ by taking the exponential of both sides, yielding
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\text{d} k}{\text{d} x}(x) = e^{-2 \ln u_1(x) - \int^x \frac{Q(x)}{P(x)}\,\text{d} x + c} =\frac{1}{u_1(x)^2} e^{- \int^x \frac{Q(x)}{P(x)}\,\text{d} x + c}.
\end{equation}

Comment: How ? Can you explain ?

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? What exactly is it that you don't understand? Which step is unclear?

Comment: I try to find result without substitution .Can you find the same result without substitution and showing steps.

Comment: Well, to be honest, no. This 'substitution' is not a trick, but merely a rewriting to show that the second order ODE for $k$ is in reality a first order ODE for $k'$, because there is no term containing $k$ in the original ODE (just $k'$ and $k''$). Solving the resulting linear first order ODE for $k'$ is just applying standard theory, which I'm sure you're able to do.

Answer (score 1):

Frits Veerman's described method:
$$k'[2Pu'_1 + Qu_1]=-[Pu_1]\frac{d(k')}{dx} \\
[2Pu'_1 + Qu_1]dx=\frac{d(k')}{k'} \\
k'=\frac{e^{-\int [Q/P]dx}}{u_1^2}$$

But when I try to direct solution based on k:

$$[2Pu'_1 + Qu_1]\frac{dk}{dx}=-[Pu_1]\frac{d(\frac{dk}{dx})}{dx} \\
\int [2Pu'_1 + Qu_1]dk=\int [Pu_1]d(\frac{dk}{dx}) \\
[2Pu'_1 + Qu_1]k=[Pu_1]\frac{dk}{dx} \\
k=\frac{e^{-\int [Q/P]dx}}{u_1^2}$$

Where exactly is my mistake ?

Comment: 1) You forgot a minus sign in your starting equation; 2) your method of solving ODEs by 'multiplying with $dx$' goes wrong. I don't blame you, because you were probably taught to do it somewhat like this, but it's not a good method because you can easily make mistakes, and it's not clear what you're *actually* doing. To stick to the format of the site, I strongly suggest you put this attempt in your original question, and I'll modify my answer to show you where you went wrong and how to repair it.

Comment: @FritsVeerman I'm looking forward to see your modification because I am still not able to see which "minus sign" , and secondly , I didn't multiply with $dx$ , it had already been there.I just wrote explicitly(for $k''$).

Comment: If you add your above attempt to your original question, I'll update my answer.

Comment: @FritsVeerman First of all , I saw and edited the solutions.Moreover , I added my attempt to the question.

Comment: Done! I hope this answers your questions.